# Tips to explore the java project which contains more than 3000 java files

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have an open source eclipse plugin project which is developed by PhD Students and it contains so many java files, I need to explore this project. Can any one please give me some suggestions/ guidance , how to explore the project?

If this question is not related to this forum , plz tell me the right forum to ask this kind of questions.

Comment: what you mean by exploring the project?Do you want to run and test the project?Or want to understand the design of the project?Are you facing any problems in loading/running the project in eclipse?

Comment: Find 3000 PhD students and give them each one file...

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK I want to understand the design and coding of the project. By using reverse engineering I generated all UML diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the following is assuming that there is decent documentation to this project -- I find it hard to imagine a 3000-file project could even be in running order without it!

One of the *the* most important things I've learned working in the professional world is that you will *never* understand the full scope of any serious code base. The first place to go is the project documentation, which typically will lay out the design/architecture of the code -- the relevant modules and how they interact with each other. If you're interested in some certain functionality, you can kind of follow the path of logic from a module of interest; or if you're interested in that particular module, you can explore the classes within that specific module. Basically what I'm saying is that good documentation is one of the most important things to a good, understandable code base; if you're going to jump in to it, the first step is having a handle on the design and architecture documentation. Once you're there, you should be able to understand the code both on a coarse and per-module level -- to get a fine grained understanding of the inner workings of one specific module, just dive into the code mentioned in the documentation!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the basics of Object oriented Programming and Java. Here I have some tips for you.

1. Study Class, Package, Use case and Sequence diagram of the project.
2. Load the project in eclipse and run the application in debug mode. Pick up some use cases of the application and understand how these use cases are implemented.
3. Identify the dependencies on third party libraries and study the usage of these libraries in the application.
4. Understand the test classes(Junit)